# How do I create a custom JSON API endpoint?

Tags: 8, nodes

I would like to create a custom JSON API endpoint to preview nodes in draft status.  The URL will be something like "jsonapi/node/page/preview".  If a page node has a draft in progress, it should be displayed instead of the published version.  If there is no draft, then the published version should be displayed.  I am new to Drupal 8, so I do not know where to start.  Could someone point me to an example, or let me know which classes I need to extend?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same question and I know that other REST services are available to customize, but I wanted to know if I could do it specifically with JSON API.